# Django manytomany and through pair

Tags: django, django-models, join

I have django models with a `manytomany` connection with a `through` class:

```
class userProfile(models.Model):
    boughtCoupons = models.ManyToManyField(Coupon, through='UserCoupons')

class UserCoupons(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(userProfile)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    date = models.DateField()


class Coupon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I know how I can get each of them individually using and ID or something to filter.

But, I need to get the Through table's value with all the user's details (profile).

So how can I do something like a JOIN, and get a UserCoupons + userProfile pair in a single query ? ( So I can get the matching user profile without an extra query ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query directly on `UserCoupons` and use [`select_related()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch also the related objects in one query:

```
UserCoupons.objects.select_related().filter(**your_filters)
```

Note that `select_related()` doesn't work "backwards". That's why you need to use a manager of the class that defines the `ForeignKey` to make it work (`UserCoupons` in this case).

Comment: Ok, but how do i get both objects then ? I get a list of coupon objects

Comment: `user_coupon = UserCoupons.objects.select_related().get(**filter); print user_coupon.user; print user_coupon.coupon;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django 1.2 or less version then jkbrzt's answer is the only solution as far as I know, since the only way to get Django to generate JOINs, without using raw SQL, is to use either `select_related()` or Django's double_*underscore notation - neither of which work on many-to-many relationships in Django 1.2 or less. However, Django's double*_underscore notation work on many-to-many in Django 1.3, so you can do the following:

```
userProfile.objects.values('boughtCoupons__name', 'usercoupons__date')
```

You have to list all the fields that you need, as far as I know, with this method which makes it a bit of a pain but never the less it is an option.